# Connect Thick thermocouple wire to Type K Connector

Tags: thermocouple

I have purchased a high-temperature K type thermocouple that has two 14 gauge solid leads. I wanted to know what the best way to go about connecting these leads to a type K connector would be.

Comment: Is "Thick" the brand name (as suggested by the capitalisation)?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would get a thermocouple plug of the same type which will ensure that the alloys match which will also provide screw clamp connections. To use these, you will need a matching thermocouple PCB jack for it to plug into. Note there is both a standard size and a miniature size.
[image]
[image]

From https://www.omega.ca/en/sensors-and-sensing-equipment/temperature/c/thermocouple-and-rtd-connectors

But if you don't care you could just use a screw terminal block. You should avoid trying to solder them.

Comment: To expound on @DKNguyen's answer: you should avoid trying to solder them because each junction of dissimilar metals acts as another thermocouple. Adding solder introduces additional metals to the junction. His answer of using matching alloys as terminal connections is correct.

Comment: @spuck Well, I was just saying avoid soldering them mainly because you'll probably fail since thermocouples metals aren't always the easiest to solder. I kind of assume that if you're already choosing to solder (or using a regular screw terminal block) then the additional junctions don't make a big enough difference to matter to you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually already have a type K connector made with the same metals. My issue is that the thermocouple wires are so thick that I can't screw them to a terminal.

Comment: @twalker You arent using a miniature connector are you? Different connectors have different AWG limits. Try another one The standard connector I just saw is listed to fits 14AWG.